# Storing radio button data in a session

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to store data in a session so that i could use it on the next page.

Here is my code where the radio buttons are used.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="payout.css"/>
<font face='calibri'>
<?php
    session_start();
    $conn = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = @mysql_select_db("");
    include("includes/functions.php");
    mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
    ?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Billing Info</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">



        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#center input[value='COD']").click(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                   $("#centerdown input[value='COD']").prop("checked", true);
                } // end if checked
            });
        }); // end doc ready

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#center input[value='PickUp']").click(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                   $("#centerdown input[value='PickUp']").prop("checked", true);
                } // end if checked
            });
        }); // end doc ready

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#center input[value='LBC']").click(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                   $("#centerdown input[value='BPI']").prop("checked", true);
                } // end if checked
            });
        }); // end doc ready


</script>

<style>
#price{
    color:red;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    float:right;
}
td{
        display:block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="hidden" name="command" />
    <div align="center">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2px">
            <tr><td><table border="0" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="1px" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px; background-color:#E1E1E1" width="500px">
        <?php
            if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
                echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td></td><td>Name</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Amount</td></tr>';
                $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
                for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                    $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
                    $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
                    $pname=get_product_prod_name($pid);
                    if($q==0) continue;


            ?>
                    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td><?php echo $i+1?></td><td><?php echo $pname?></td>
                    <td>₱<?php echo number_format(get_prod_price($pid),2)?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product<?php echo $pid?>" value="<?php echo $q?>" maxlength="2" size="2" disabled/></td>                    
                    <td>₱<?php echo number_format((get_prod_price($pid)*$q),2)?></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php                   
                }
            ?>
                <tr><td></td><td colspan="5" align='right'><b>Order Total: ₱<?php echo get_order_total()?></b></td></tr>
            <?php
            }
            else{
                echo "<tr bgColor='#FFFFFF'><td>There are no items in your shopping cart!</td>";
            }
        ?>

        </table></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
                    <center><h1>Shipping Method</h1></center>
            <form method="post">
            <table width="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id='center'>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="LBC") echo "checked";?>  value="LBC"></td>
                    <td><img src="../paymentoptions/LBC.jpg" alt="LBC" class="picture"/></td>
                    <td><p>The Shipping takes 1-2 days for NCR and 2-3 days for any provincial.<p>
                        <!--<div id='price'> Additional ₱250 </div></td>-->

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="PickUp") echo "checked";?>  value="PickUp"></td>
                    <td><img src="../paymentoptions/Pick-up.jpg" alt="Pick-Up" class="picture"/></td>
                    <td><p>Office hours: 10:00 am to 5:00 pm<p>
                        <!--<div id='price'> Free!! </div></td>-->
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <br>
        <center><h1>Payment Method</h1></center>
        <table width="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id='centerdown'>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" disabled name="payment" <?php if (isset($payment) && $payment=="BPI") echo "checked";?>  value="BPI"></td>
                    <td><img src="../paymentoptions/BPI.jpg"></td>
                    <td><p>Pay by BPI bank deposit (we need confirmation of payment through email.)<p></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" disabled name="payment" <?php if (isset($payment) && $payment=="PickUp") echo "checked";?>  value="PickUp"></td>
                    <td><img src="../paymentoptions/Pick-up.jpg"></td>
                    <td><p>Pick up. You have 5 days reservation period. You pay for the merchandise upon pick-up<p></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <table>
            <tr><td><input type="button" value="View Shopping Cart" onclick="window.location='shoppingcart.php?'"></td><td><input type="button" name="order" value="Place Order" onclick="window.location='billing.php?'"/> <!--<input type="button" value="Confirm Order" onclick="window.location='quotation.php?'">--></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['order'])){
    $_SESSION['carrier'] = $carrier;
    $_SESSION['payment'] = $payment;
}
?>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I think what i placed at the bottom are wrong. haha. I have no idea how to do it, Thanks for looking!

Comment: where is your post processing done?

if (isset($_POST['order'])){
    $_SESSION['carrier'] = $carrier;
    $_SESSION['payment'] = $payment;
}

Will only run on a post execute, meaning it wont run unless you are getting to this page WITH a post. Which will do you no good on the post processing page.

Comment: Hmm Originally I made a page that would store it in the database. but since im trying to add a new page, i dont need it to store immediately in the database but in the session first so the user can confirm before storing it in the database, before the post processing is done in the same page but i removed the codes that would input it in the same page. @jjonesdesign

Comment: After looking over it again, I believe maybe 'order' is not being set to post on submit. You are asking by reference for the name of your button, which I believe is not included in your post information. Instead add a name to your FORM and use that.

Comment: I did what you said and added a name to the form, and changed $carrier into $_POST['carrier'] and the other one. but nothing happened @jjonesdesign

Comment: oh duh! I am looking at this wrong. You are setting your sessions "$_SESSION['carrier'] = $carrier;" from a local variable that is unset on page load. try $_SESSION['carrier'] = $_POST['carrier'];

Comment: i did that too @jjonesdesign but when i echo it in another page using echo $_SESSION['carrier']; it doesnt work.

Comment: Hmm, I seem to be missing something here. It's probably the smallest thing too. Have you tried putting an echo in where your setting session 'carrier' to ensure this section of code is working?

Comment: Okay after changing the input type to submit, and adding echo in the same page, it did display the result. but now how do i transfer to the next page? @jjonesdesign

Comment: These variables should be stored now in session memory. These will be available on any page a session is started, until overwritten or destroyed, or by browser closing/timing out. You can call them: $somthing = $_SESSION['carrier']; or how ever you need to use them. <input name='blah' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['carrier'];?>'>

Comment: Yeah @jjonesdesign but how do i upvote a comment im only at 1 reputation, create an answer so i can just choose that one.

Comment: Thanks! Glad we got that sorted out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These variables should be stored now in session memory. 

These will be available on any page a session is started, until overwritten or destroyed, or by browser closing/timing out. 

You can call them:

```
$somthing = $_SESSION['carrier'];
```

or how ever you need to use them.

```
 <input name='blah' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['carrier'];?>'>
```